# Filter rows in datagridview by key press

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got the following code which restricts the user to typing only numbers into a textbox.

How would I then use the numerical values that are typed in to filter the rows in my datagrid (**dataGridView1**) by matching what is written in the **driverNo** textbox to what is in the **DriverNo** column?

This is my code so far:

```
private void driverNo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to filter the rows being shown if the row contains the numerical key that was pressed?

Comment: Yep but only in the DriverNo column

Comment: You can check if the `SelectedColumns` `Text.Contains` the `driverNo` key pressed.  And just act upon the Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to hide all rows that have the number as in your textbox (let's call it `textBox1`).

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["driverNo"].Value != null
        && row.Cells["driverNo"].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Note that if your `DataGridView` is bounded to DataSet you should first need to suspend data binding.

**EDIT:**

If you want the filtering to occur while user typing (on the fly), you can attach this code to the `KeyUp` event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["driverNo"].Value != null
            && row.Cells["driverNo"].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
        {
            row.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can optimize this code to eliminate the loop with the use of lookup or hash table. But this basically works fine (have not tested on big data grid).

Comment: I guess you should have a submit button for your textBox. Or you would like it to happen on-the-fly while user is typing? If it's the second case then I guess you should treat the opposite case of showing back the rows.

Comment: It would have to happen on the fly