# Use datagridview columns added from the designer on data table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a datagridview in designer view and added columns to it. My question is how I can access these columns from my DataTable object instead of again manually adding columns to the Datatable again(Re use columns added from datagridview on Datatable). This is what have done so far

```
void loadData()
        {

            dt = new DataTable();
          

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Argentina", 2000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Belgium", 4500 });
   

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
```

and here is my columns in datagrid[image: this]

I need to use BindingSource class to filter data and i dont know how else i can do it so that I have columns added from the designer and am able to filter datagrid. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245000/filter-datagrid-view-from-data-populated-from-entity-in-c-sharp) is the post that I had previously posted to get help on how to filter datagridview but the solutions seems is have to bind data using datasource. I need to maintain the style and format applied to the datagridview columns on the designer

Comment: You can create a filtered datatable and then make the filtered table your datasource : DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => your filter).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @jdweng then how can i maintain my custom columns from datagridview desginer

Comment: Then if you have 2nd table dt2 use : foreach(DataRow row in dt2.AsEnumerable()) { dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { row[0], row[1]}); }

Comment: @jdweng how can i access the datagridview columns from DataTable that is what am not getting

Comment: The view probably is not getting repainted.  The trick is to set datasource to null. dataGridView1.DataSource = null; dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;

Comment: @jdweng I think u are not getting my point here. u see I have designed columns from designer and have applied format. so what i need is to use datatable object to fill those columns without creating columns on the datatable

Comment: @jdweng look at the datagrid view image i shared, that wat i want to populate using datagrid view then check on the comments on the datatable to explain what i need to achieve

Comment: I proposing creating a new table with just the columns you need from original table and then make the new table to datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're manually adding the data, there's no use of adding them to a datatable then setting it as the datasource, you can just;

```
void loadData(){
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Argentina", 2000 });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Belgium", 4500 });
}
```

This is, the order of the Object array must match the order of the columns in your datagridview.

Regarding your question about filtering, the problem is that you don't provide where the data actually comes from, normally you would like to filter the data when retrieving them. If in case the data is manually added, then you can just loop through the datagridview and check for your filter, although with this the databinding capability of the datagridview is really not utilized.

Comment: where is the code to re use datagridview columns on datable that is what am lacking?

Comment: What I get from your question is that you don't want the lines of code with `dt.Columns.Add()` but it can't be because it will not match your manually added data from the `dt.Rows.Add()`

Comment: so I cannot use datagridview columns on datatable?

Comment: In your case since you manually fill the DataTable, you can't.

Comment: Think about it, your datagridview is a control that displays the data, it does have columns but in your datatable, without setting the columns, where does "Argentina" go, where does "2000" go?

Comment: Wait, actually you can. Since you are manually adding the data anyway, why not directly add them to the datagridview?

Comment: then how can I filter datagrid as posted in my previous post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245000/filter-datagrid-view-from-data-populated-from-entity-in-c-sharp

Comment: have seen your code, now with that approach how do I filter data on textbox keypress

Comment: The question is only about  `Use datagridview columns added from the designer on data table`

Comment: help me on how i can filter the data on the code you shared, I will accept and upvote your answer

Comment: thanks atleast you gave me an hint on filtering wat i should do and got this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523052/filter-rows-in-datagridview-by-key-press